# How to loop through a file only when a date is a certain day

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib

I have a large data file that has over 5 million lines. The data is over a span 6 months.The data file has two data points. Date & time start and Date & Time end. My goal is to see how many concurrent connections there are for each record.

I was able to make what I want with looping the entire file for each line. However that is really not efficient and takes a significant amount of time to process for large datasets.

Is it possible to change the code so it only looks at data where the date listed in the file equals the current line it is on?

I can add break apart of data to different sections if need be.

Here is a sample of my data.

```
2020-07-04 17:28:48,2020-07-04 17:29:15
2020-07-04 17:12:47,2020-07-04 17:13:01
2020-07-04 17:45:02,2020-07-04 17:45:19
2020-07-04 17:33:05,2020-07-04 17:33:22
2020-07-04 17:33:39,2020-07-04 17:33:49
2020-07-04 17:46:07,2020-07-04 17:46:20
2020-07-05 10:17:26,2020-07-05 10:17:44
2020-07-05 10:36:33,2020-07-05 10:36:51
2020-07-05 11:15:14,2020-07-05 11:16:03
2020-07-05 10:59:47,2020-07-05 11:00:18
```

Here is my current code to loop through the entire file

```
active_events= []
for i in df.index:
    active_events.append(len(df[(df["date_start"]<=df.loc[i,"date_start"]) & 
                                (df["date_end"]> df.loc[i,"date_start"])]))
df['activecalls'] = pd.Series(active_events)
```

An example of what I want it do is if the current line is

```
2020-07-04 17:33:39,2020-07-04 17:33:49
```

Then it will only loop through the file where the date equals 2020-07-04 and find where there are other connections that are going on at the same time. And not look at any other line in the file.

If I am able to make that change, it will significantly cut down the required processing time. Would anybody be able to help me? Or if there is better solution to this.

Comment: In your examples, every connection starts and ends on the same day. Is that always the case? Or do some connections last for more than a day?

Comment: All connections start and end on the same day.

Comment: This appears to be a prime case for using "groupby": gather the data rows (not file lines) by date, and process each group as you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Loop through the file exactly once, and count the number of connections with a structure storing a counter for each day.**

In python, you can either do that with a list of size 183 (the number of days in six months), and index each day by its number between 0 and 182; or with a dictionary, and index each day by its date as a string.

Using a dictionary:

```py
import collections

data = '''2020-07-04 17:28:48,2020-07-04 17:29:15
2020-07-04 17:12:47,2020-07-04 17:13:01
2020-07-04 17:45:02,2020-07-04 17:45:19
2020-07-04 17:33:05,2020-07-04 17:33:22
2020-07-04 17:33:39,2020-07-04 17:33:49
2020-07-04 17:46:07,2020-07-04 17:46:20
2020-07-05 10:17:26,2020-07-05 10:17:44
2020-07-05 10:36:33,2020-07-05 10:36:51
2020-07-05 11:15:14,2020-07-05 11:16:03
2020-07-05 10:59:47,2020-07-05 11:00:18'''

d = collections.defaultdict(int)

for line in data.split('\n'):
  date = line.split()[0]
  d[date] += 1
 
print(d)
```

Output: `defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'2020-07-04': 6, '2020-07-05': 4})`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to take a look at this. I must have explained it wrong. I was hoping for the result be something show for each individual record, how many concurrent connections there are during the two times.

For Example, 2020-07-04 17:12:47,2020-07-04 17:13:01  I would want to get a count of all connections where there are other records where the time is inside this time.

Answer (score -1):

You could try a while loop and end it whenever the dates are found you can quit a program.